# Show DatePicker even if DateTextField is disabled

Tags: datepicker, wicket, show, disabled-input

How can I show the DatePicker and "write" in the DateTextField, when it is disabled. I don't want to allow the user to set manually dates. He has to choose one from the DatePicker. At the moment, the DatePicker-Icon doesn't show up, if the Textfield is disabled. (setEnabled(false)).

Answer (score 0):

You could trick it by changing the `HTML`. You could add `style='display:none'` to the textfield. Another option would be to render the texfield as `readonly`

Technically there are still ways to set the date in that textfield (by javascript or making the textfield visible by changing CSS), but a normal user would not do such things.